# How to add new value into list in R

Tags: r

I was looking for some solution about adding new value into list. Eg. I have list of values

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) 
x = list(n, s, b, 3)   # x contains copies of n, s, b
```

and I need to add value 6 to list x to have in x[[1]] 2, 3, 5, 6 values.

How do I do that?

Comment: No problem.  Added the comment as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
x[[1]] <- c(x[[1]],6)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
   x[[1]] <- append(x = x[[1]],values = 6)
```

works also.